# Triple nested quotes in XML

Tags: xml

As part of a build script for a tool based on ANT (Phing):

```
<exec command="ssh x@y.com 'hg commit -m `Message`'"/>
```

Only that ` isn't accepted, either is \' and I'd rather not call a script file on the remote server with the hg command in it.

Anything else feasible?

**Update1:** added in attribute name that I'd forgotten to transcribe over.

Also expanding on 'isn't accepted', (which it was for the backtick, just not acceptable for my purpose):

Using backticks around Message: underlying shell will interpret Message as a command
Using esaped quotes (\') around Message: `sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string`

**Update2:** `&quot;` appears to have done the trick.

Comment: You appear to have an attribute value without an attribute name. That isn't XML.

Comment: Why are you trying to escape `\`` by replacing the backtick with a straight quote *and* prefixing it with a backslash?

Comment: What do you mean "isn't accepted"? How do you know? Do you get an error message? What does the error say? What part of the system emitted the error?

Comment: Oops, I put the attribute value in. Trimmed it too much.

Comment: Any chance you could use an element containing CDATA instead of an attribute?  I'm not familiar with ANT, so that may not be possible, but CDATA is the normal way to handle data that you don't want the XML parser to parse (because it contains illegal XML characters and such).

Comment: I was hoping to not have to go there Tim for readability but thanks anyway. Damien's &quot; suggestion looks to work at this stage.

Comment: Can you show us the command line you would _like_ to have?

Comment: ssh x@y.com 'hg commit -m "hello world"'

Comment: But note it has been solved, I just can't accept a comment.

Comment: Don't accept a comment. Answer your own question. You can then accept your own answer before long. Make it a good answer and you'll even get upvotes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Damien indicated in the comments, using `&quot;` as the third level of quoting solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you could use

```
<exec command="echo hg commit -m 'Message' | ssh x@y.com"/>
```